# What games other than Ars Magica encourage Troupe play?

Tags: campaign-development, history-of-gaming, group-dynamics, ars-magica-5

Troupe play is a specific style where the group is encouraged to collaborate in creating and running the game. There's often more than one GM, players often run more than one character and, indeed, there may be a "pool" of characters which they share.

More details on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troupe_system).

I first encountered this in the game Ars Magica and that Wikipedia article says that's where it originated, which was also my understanding. It also says it is used in some other games, where it is called "collaborative role-playing". I've seen that claim made elsewhere.

However, I can't recall ever having encountered another game which even suggested this approach to play, let alone made it a central feature as Ars Magica does.

So: what other systems have been influenced by Ars Magica to include elements of troupe-style play?

Comment: I played this way with D&D in the 1980s - we didn't give it a name

Comment: Totally bemused as to how this is off-topic. I am not interested in "shopping" or "recommendation". I want to chart how the idea of Ars Magica spread through other systems!

Comment: There are thousands of published systems, many more are unpublished and any of them might have been influenced by troupe-like play from Ars Magica or a related game. It is both a shopping/recommendation, a list of things, and massively over broad.

Comment: @Sardathrion So by that logic, there's no way a question about relationships between systems can *ever* be on topic, unless the question lists two or more specific games?

Comment: Meta opened on this question here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7446